# Visual Studio Code suggestions and autoclose are not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some issues with my Visual Studio Code. After installing a fresh copy of it, and cleaned all the items stored by it, the autoclose plugin, the suggestion plugins are not working at all. All autosuggestions are prefixed by the icon [abc], the wrench key or blank file.

List of my plugins:

- Angular 2 TypeScript Emmet
- Angular 2 TypeScript Test Snippets
- Angular 2+ Snippets - TypeScript, Html, ngRx, Angular Flex Layout, Material & Testing
- Angular Files
- Angular CLI
- Angular v4 TypeScript Snippets
- Auto Close tag
- Auto Import
- Beautify
- Beautify CSS/sass/scss/less
- CSS Peak
- Debugger for Chrome
- File Peek
- Find all references
- Highlight matching taf
- HTML CSS Support
- IntelliSense for CSS class
- JavaScript ES6 code snippet
- JavaScript and TypeScript IntelliSense
- JavaScript Snippet Pack
- jQuery Code Snippets
- jslint
- Less IntelliSense
- Path IntelliSense
- PHP IntelliSense
- Prettify JSON
- Stylesheet Formatter
- Twig
- TWIG pack

And all of them looks like something is not working. Here are some example of this issue:

[image: autosuggestions]
[image: autosuggestions]

Thanks!